# Can't delete row using Npgsql adapter if there is char column in primary key

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

all.

I have a PostgreSQL table which primary key has a column with type CHAR(20), so value 'X' is stored as 'X[19 spaces]' in the table. I can't delete a row from this table using NpgsqlDataAdapter, I always get an exception "System.Data.DBConcurrencyException: Concurrency violation: the DeleteCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.". I guess those spaces somehow are messing with adapter and it can't find a row to delete. I'm using data adapters for all operations with the database, so I can't use some dirty hacks like executing 'delete from' scripts.

Here is my code to reproduce this behaviour:

```
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("select * from chartest", connection))
    using (var builder = new NpgsqlCommandBuilder(adapter))
    {
        //drop table to make a clean test
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "drop table if exists chartest";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //create table for testing
        command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE chartest (charcol CHAR(20) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_chartest PRIMARY KEY (charcol))";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //add one row with value 'z' which expands to 'z                   ' after saving
        command.CommandText = "insert into chartest (charcol) values ('z')";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //load table from database
        var table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);

        //try to delete row...
        table.Rows[0].Delete();
        adapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();
        adapter.Update(table);//...and get an exception System.Data.DBConcurrencyException: 
        //Concurrency violation: the DeleteCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't change the type of this field or make any other changes to the database. I'v tried to:

- manually create DeleteCommand with each parameter;
- reject row changes, trim value, delete row again: 1) in RowUpdating event
  handler 2) before calling Update method
- change column's MaxLength to the actual length of a value;
- change DbParameter's Size to the actual length of a value;
- add trim functions to CommandText of DeleteCommand;
- use different Npgsql libraries (2.2.3 and 3.2.1);
- use different .NET Framework versions (4.0 and 4.5.1);
- study Npgsql source code.

But still no luck. Could you please help me? How can I make the adapter delete such rows? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Github: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1453

Comment: Well, looks like I find a workaround. This code in RowUpdating event handler will do the trick: (e.Command.Parameters[0] as NpgsqlParameter).Value = (e.Command.Parameters[0] as NpgsqlParameter).Value.ToString().Trim();